# Is it possible to use policy based design together with automated testing?

Tags: templates, optimization, automated-tests, generic-programming

I am developing a numerical simulations library which is centred around a single collection of data operated on by different computational algorithms. The algorithms are complex, they have different states involving multiple parameters, and are interchangeable (under some semantic restrictions).

To avoid bloated interface of the collection and to enable different implementations etc, I'm thinking about using policy based design. This gives the collection a wide combination of choices between storage structures, algorithms, parameters, internal stuff.

If I imagine that I redesigned my generic / object oriented existing design usign policies, how can I choose the optimal algorithms and data structures? Conceptually I need to define the set of policies and a set of verification test cases and execute a parametric study.

This is easy when object oriented programming is used since I can determine all necessary types and their parameters during run-time using e.g. a string-based Abstract Factory with type names stored in the input file, that is then changed by an external script that executes the client application on a family of test cases.

How do I do that with policies, where a combination of N policies ends up in being N different client applications?

How is automated testing done together with policy based design in a professional way?

Comment: Like you hinted, there's no way to do this at runtime!  Sounds like you'd need to write a script to gen up all the possible permutations of policies, and somehow just paste that into your performance test code.  I don't know of any off-the-shelf tools that do this sort of thing, but maybe someone else will :)

Comment: I'm thinking about editing macros in cobination with an external script that stores the type names in table and permutes them, and then it invokes the compiler and after that, an automatic testing suite: the client application allways has the same name in this case. But I wonder what is used in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're representing algorithms as policies, you /should/ have a pretty uniform interface already thought up. You could imagine an "AlgorithmPolicy" processing some data from your data store and returning some representation of the results.

"If I imagine that I redesigned my generic / object oriented existing design usign policies, how can I choose the optimal algorithms and data structures?"

If your object oriented design currently makes use of the strategy pattern (see also: the Gang of Four book), your policies will simply replace every place that you've used a strategy. Choosing "optimal algorithms" for the different policies you design will simply be a matter of nailing the right conceptual structure / interface for those policies. (If you're going to use many different data stores, make sure that the interface for adding / removing / getting data from them is uniform, for example. Here, it can be helpful to think of three examples and find commonalities... then think of another exmaple and make sure it fits the schema. Iterate until things feel correct.)

You'll still have adequate type checking, it'll just feel a bit different (and you may run into some nasty compile errors occaisionally. ;)

Testing will simply be a matter of writing some unit tests for each of the configurations / policy combinations you'd like to cover. You probably should already be writing these tests anyways; the primary difference is that you'll want to try to hit the interfaces you designate rather than targetting specifics.

You can validate different storage methods based on validations of your algorithm policies. (So, if I have some algorithm that can be stored in different ways, I can run the algorithm on some test data for ecah storage mechanism and expect the same results.) Assuming that you've spec'd out the inteface correclty, you should only need to write a single test for each additional storage mechanism you add.

Again: It'd be nice to have more details about the structure of the program, what different parameters and such you'd need to pass in. (Is any of this code open source / going to be open sourced?)

From what you've said, in my mind, your complicated-policy process may have an interface like so:

FancyDataStore.Process()

For testing it, I'd write: 
 MockAlgorithmPolicy - A very simple algorithm that's trivial to validate. 
 MockInternalStuffPolicy - A very simple internal stuff policy that causes no integrations / reports nothing new. 
 MockStoragePolicy - A very simple storage policy that meets your interface for storage / doesn't cause many issues.

Write a test that validates the mocks put together...
For each StoragePolicy you create, write an automated test to validate it:

```
testSomeStoragePolicy{ 
// has a call to: 
FancyDataStore.Process<MockAlgorithmPolicy, SomeStoragePolicy, MockInternalStuff>() 
// validate... 
}
```

That should prove that the SomeStoragePolicy works as expected.

Then, for your algorithms, you could write:

```
testSomeAlgorithmPolicy{
FancyDataStore.process<SomeAlgorithmPolicy, MockStoragePolicy, MockInternalStuff>(); 
///Validate. 
}
```

etc. 
This way, you write basically 1 test per each policy you end up writing (which seems feasible and not too ridiculous) Additionally, you can always add additional unit tests to cover other subtle integrations that may spin up over time.

If you're looking for good books on this subject, I'd suggest reading "Modern C++ Programming"; it provides a great primer on policy-driven design in C++.

Comment: Thanks, I came to the same conclusion: I'll use the policy based design and determine reasonable test configurations. For those configurations, I'll make the script configure the templates, compile and execute the test set. Thanks for the hint regarding the book, I already read it, but the chapter on Policy based design doens't explain automatic testing. :)